# Neo.ApplicationFramework "The name ... does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#

I'm dabbling in C# to write some scripts in what is otherwise a graphical machine interface programming environment (Beijer's iX Developer). The HMI is monitoring 'tags' (variables) in a PLC (programmable logic controller).

When tag Controller1_M18 turns on I want to print a report and then reset the tag. This code I'm putting in the Tags Script module is giving me error "The name 'PrintReport' does not exist in the current context". Can anyone give me guidance in fixing it?

```
namespace Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated
{
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Graphics.Logic;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Interfaces;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.Reporting;

    public partial class Report_Functions
    {
        void Controller1_M18_ValueOn(System.Object sender, Neo.ApplicationFramework.Interfaces.Events.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Print the report.
            PrintReport("BatchReport1");
            // Reset the tag.
            Globals.Tags.Controller1_M18.ResetTag();
        }
    }
}
```

The sparse scripting help file gives the information

```
Namespace: Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.Reporting
Assembly: ToolsCF (in ToolsCF.dll) Version: 2.15.5714.0

Syntax
public void PrintReport(
    string reportName
)
```

ToolsCF.dll is present in the application folder along with all the others.

Comment: @DavidG, I notice you removed C# from the question. Is that not relevant when the framework supports or works with VB and C++? (I have no idea.)

Comment: I removed it from the title only, note the tag is still present. Further reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @DavidG, thanks. I agree with some of the Meta comments that this policy is flawed. The tags don't show up in the "Questions" listing (so the reader has lost a big clue about the subject matter) and they show up at the _bottom_ of the question. They're really only of use when searching by topic or on the _Related_ sidebar. Let's see if anyone finds my question!

Comment: The majority of the people answering questions on here (including me) add tags to their favourites and only look at them. Tags in question titles will almost always get removed.

Comment: Is the PrintReport method part of a class? That would be my initial thought here.

Comment: The help listing doesn't seem to be valid since C# doesn't allow free functions (e.g. functions outside classes/structs). My guess would be that the `PrintReport` method is defined on some class and you need to use its instance to call it. The unqualified lookup in your case would only consider `Report_Functions` class and its extensions and it looks like it's not defined in there.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I pass tag name as String in ix Developer.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are attempting to call, `PrintReport` simply doesn't exist in the class you have created. Either you have copy pasted this code from somewhere and missed that out or you are trying to reference a method in a different class. It's impossible to tell any more than this from the limited information provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated.Globals.Reports.PrintReport("BatchReport1");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! While this may answer the question, it doesn't provide the asker any context. Consider adding some more explanation on why the fully qualified name is necessary. It also appears that this would assume a static method, which `PrintReport` does not appear to be from the OP's edit.